# Skip build altogether but generate platform dependant sources in SCons

Tags: xcode, scons

I have a project that uses SCons to generate platform dependent source files which are compiled together with other shipped source files into static libraries and linked into the final executable, and that's it, no project files are generated for my IDE (Xcode)

I managed to add SCons as an external build system in a new Xcode project to build and debug the executable

What I want now is to customize the source code and add a few libraries removing Scons altogether as external build system. Scons is not practical in my case, too slow, and I don't want to mess with the scripts.

**So the question is whether there is a feature in SCons to skip the build process but just generate the platform dependent source files?**

Edit:

I would like to make some customizations to the project and not mess with SCons at least until I need to do pull requests, that was my workfow with a previous project that used CMake to generate the Xcode project, SCons would require to modify the scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding `Export()` in `SConstruct` like the the code from below and adding the parameter `skip_build` to the script, which sets the value of __SkipBuild, I was able to skip the build process altogether (i.e. compiling and linking), generating only the platform dependent sources

**SConstruct**

```
__Export = Export
__CommandsList = ['CC','CXX','AR','RANLIB','AS','LINK'] # The commands to skip from the build process
__SkipBuild = False

def Export(*vars, **kw):
    for var in vars:
        locals()[var] = call_stack[-1].globals[var]
        if (call_stack[-1].globals['__SkipBuild']):
            for command in __CommandsList:
                if locals()[var].has_key(command):
                    locals()[var][command] = 'echo ' + locals()[var][command]
    call_stack[-1].globals.update(kw)
    __Export(locals(), kw)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can specify the targets that you want to get built on the command-line explicitly:

```
scons lib1/source1.cpp sourceb.cpp
```

would be an example.

Since you mentioned that SCons would be "too slow" for you, how exactly did you measure that (see http://scons.org/wiki/WhySconsIsNotSlow and http://scons.org/wiki/GoFastButton )?

Comment: The benchmarks in the first link show SCons slower than make for several orders of magnitude in most cases. Also I'm updating the question to add a few observations about why SCons is slow in my case.

Comment: Yes, and the rest of the page explains why this behaviour was observed under the given circumstances (which rarely fit a real-life project) and what can be done about it (how SCons can be sped up). If you have truly performance issues with SCons, I'm genuinely interested in hearing about them and trying to improve your situation. But from your latest edit I got the impression that it's more about "you simply don't want to mess with SCons"...which is perfectly fine with me. Let's leave it at that...however, I invite you over to scons-users@scons.org where we could discuss things further.